# Using a bash script with SCP to choose directory on remote server

Tags: bash, escaping, quotes

My problem is that I would like to write a bash script to upload a file to a remote server, and use the file name to determine which directory on the remote server to use. The script below captures the first part of the file name to determine the directory on the remote server.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
regex="(.*) S([0-9]{2})E([0-9]{2}) (.*)\.mp4"
for filename; do
    if [[ "$filename" =~ $regex ]]; then
        a=`echo scp \"$filename\" mal@serenity.local:\'\"/Volumes/Vault/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"\'`
        eval $a
fi
done
```

My difficulty is that this script works fine for files where the part of the filename that determines the directory is a single word. Herdmasters S01E14 Three Men on the Same Horse.mp4, for example, directs the file to the "Herdmasters" directory on the remote server. It also works when the first part has spaces - Bonehead the Clown S03E15 My Stupid Dog.mp4 also works.

When the filename contains an apostrophe or quote, however, the wheels come off - I'd Hit That S02E09 Well, Maybe Not That.mp4 throws a mismatched quote error.

What steps do I need to take to properly escape quotes, parentheses, and the like, provided I don't have prior knowledge of the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**. Jump to "Solution to the problem".

#### Educational material

Two lessons from your script:

1. Always quote parameter expansion unless you have a valid reason not to.
2. Avoid `eval` at all cost (or at least use it very cautiously), and **never** use it with arbitrary strings.

The first point should be obvious, the second one needs some explanation. So here it goes.

Your `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` can be practically anything, **and `eval`ing arbitrary strings may lead to arbitrary damage**. You can easily blow your computer away with a malicious filename. For instance, say a malicious file is named `"'; ls $HOME; echo ' S01E01 whatever.mp4`. When you run it through your script, you will execute `ls $HOME`. In case you want to see it for yourself, just try the following snippet, which puts `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` for the filename above in `$malicious_string` (`set -x` lets you see what is being executed):

```
set -x
malicious_string="\"'; ls \$HOME; echo '"
a=`echo scp \"$filename\" mal@serenity.local:\'\"/Volumes/Vault/$malicious_string\"\'`
eval $a
```

The commands you executed at the end, according to `set -x`, are

```
scp '' 'mal@serenity.local:"/Volumes/Vault/"'; ls /Users/johndoe; echo '"'
```

Imagine if I replaced `ls $HOME` with `rm -rf $HOME`.

---

#### Solution to the problem

In this case you don't need `eval` at all, although quoting the filename for `scp` is still an annoyance. `scp` expects you to pass a quoted path readable by the remote shell. Therefore, what you could do is add single quotes around the path, and escape every occurrence of single quote `'` with `'\''` (explanation of `'\''`: the first `'` closes the previous single quote, `\'` is a literal single quote, and the last `'` starts a new round of quoting). For instance, try

```
stupid_name=$'word \n $`\"'\'  # This is the most stupid filename ever, with space, $, `, ", \, and '
quoted_stupid_name=\'${stupid_name//\'/\'\\\'\'}\'  # This command wraps $stupid_name in single quotes and replace each occurrenceof ' with '\''
touch file && scp file user@domain:"$quoted_stupid_name"
```

Putting it together, your final product is

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="(.*) S([0-9]{2})E([0-9]{2}) (.*)\.mp4"
for filename; do
    if [[ "$filename" =~ $regex ]]; then
        remote_filename="/Volumes/Vault/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        quoted_remote_filename=\'${remote_filename//\'/\'\\\'\'}\'
        scp "$filename" mal@serenity.local:"$quoted_remote_filename"
done
```

Comment: That said, the easiest solution of all is to not have whitespace and special characters in filenames. Saves tons of trouble...

Comment: this is exactly the level of help I needed. Not only have you developed a solution to my problem, but explained why my previous approach was a dangerous idea, and consequently saved me from a risk of damage I didn't even know I was subject to. I'm very much obliged; thanks for your time.

Comment: @user2480136 You can actually accept this answer and hence mark the problem solved by clicking the check mark to the left of this answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks very much indeed.